# Android Studio ~ games.applications.played Api Error, scores won't submit after Apk Release

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-play-games

I'm utterly confused and stuck. My highscores worked prior to release. Worked 100%. Now I've released and now I've hit constant problems. The biggest is highscores issues. The code is fine. Logs show no errors at all. It's an api issue as the console throws up two errors that apparently have something to do with my release AUTHID. The two errors are as follows:

**games.applications.played: 100**

**games.scores.submitMultiple: 100**

My code is below :

```
public void playerscores() {
        if (apiClient != null && apiClient.isConnected()) {
            Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(apiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_highscores, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                            LeaderboardScore c = arg0.getScore();
                            String score = c.getDisplayScore();
                            GameSurface.HighScore = Integer.parseInt(score);
                            saver.saveString(HIGHSCORE, score);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Anyway This is my main issue at the moment. This Method is called and should post the highscore. However it does nothing, and then it wont let me open the highscores again in the game. It just wont load. Ive Checked and my AUTHID is fine, my App id matches, everything seems like it should just work. I have no idea whats wrong

```
public void gameover() {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(apiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_highscores), GameSurface.HighScore);
}
```

I've checked my sha1 it matches, I've unzipped release checked, sha1 matches, Auth ID matches everything matches up, debug Auth still in place, I really don't know what's wrong, Please any help will be appreciated I'm really confused.

**To summarise, Google games logs me in. I can open highscore, play game, get a score, die, no post happens, can't open highscores anymore.**

Comment: And What happens if you only link the app to the store. Because That's all I do. I do get SHA1 key after that but evertything seem to work ok. So why do you need to upload another debug key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add it to Linked Apps in Google Play Console.
You should have at least two linked apps one with debug sha1 key and one with release sha1 key.
Having it only in Google Cloud Platform is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check those steps:

### In the Google Developers Console

1. Create an **OAuth 2.0 client ID** for this particular version, you will need the package name and its specific SH1 key.
2. If you restricted your API key to Android applications, the same SH1 key and package name should be listed in the API key.

### In the Google Play Console

1. Select the game in the Game Service section, then click the **Associated Applications** menu.
2. Click **Associate another application** and select **Android**.
3. Fill the form, you will have to select the application in the **Package name** field.
4. If it is the Play Store version, you would want to check **Priority for new players**
5. Click the **Save** button.

That is all.